# Can't synchronize more than 2 threads with pthread_mutex_lock

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

So I'm doing homework for my C class and I came across a problem. I want to sync the acess to my global array with pthread_mutex_lock() but it seems that when 2 or more threads try to lock at the same time it just bugs. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 10
#define VAL 10


int numbers[49];

pthread_mutex_t mutex;


typedef struct {
    int start;
    int* vec;
} dados;

void* threadFunction(void *arg){
    dados* d = (dados*) arg;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int count[49];
    memset(count, 0, 49);
    for(i = 0; i < 49; i++){    
        for(j = d->start; j < (d->start + VAL); j++) {
            if(d->vec[j] == i+1)
                count[i] = d->vec[j];
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for(i = 0; i < 49; i++) {       
        numbers[i]+= count[i];  
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    free(d);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    srand(time(NULL));
    /*=============== Threads ================*/
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    /*========================================*/
    int vec[NUM_THREADS * VAL];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS * VAL; i++)
        vec[i] = (int)(rand() % 49 + 1);

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        dados* d = malloc(sizeof(dados));
        d->start = i*VAL;
        d->vec = vec;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadFunction, d);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); 

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    for(i = 0 ; i < 49; i++)
        printf("NUMERO %d = %d\n", i+1, numbers[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `just bugs`: what does it mean?

Comment: You most likely have problem with your index calculations leading to an out-of-bound error. Please cook your problem down to a minimal example and then learn to use a debugger. At least almost certain it is not the mutex stuff itself.

Comment: `d->vec = vec;` doesn't seem right. Are you sure you want all threads working on the same data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two bugs

```
memset(count, 0, 49);
```

should be:

```
memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));
```

And..

```
           count[i] = d->vec[j];
```

should be:

```
           count[i]++;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i thought it was related to the mutex, you cleared it out for me.